# PySpark: nested-splitting one column into multiple new ones

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a `network.log` on Hadoop:

`{"Source":"Network","Detail":"Event=01|Device=Mobile|ClientIP=10.0.0.0|URL=example.com"}`

I want to load it as a data frame splitting `Detail` with `|`. Then I want to further split each new column using `=` with left part as the column names and right part as the values.

The expected result would be:

```
Source  | Event | Device | ClientIP | URL
Network | 01    | Mobile | 10.0.0.0 | example.com
```

I've done the first split as follows:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions, SQLContext

INPUT_PATH = 'network.log'

sc = SparkContext("local", "NetworkEvent")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

raw = sqlContext.read.json(INPUT_PATH)

detail_col = functions.split(raw['Detail'], '\|')

for i in range(4):
    raw = raw.withColumn('col_' + str(i), detail_col.getItem(i))

raw.show()
```

My question is, can I do the second split at the same time on top of `detail_col.getItem(i)`? I can think of creating another UDF for each column of the new data frame but is there a more elegant way in one UDF? Many thanks!

Note: I'm using Spark 1.5.0 so Pandas' UDFs won't be available.

Comment: Is your number of columns in details a fixed number ? you always have the same cols ?

Comment: @Steven yes each record has same schema i.e. fixed number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 1.5.0, you can use `regexp_extract`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

for i in ['Event', 'Device', 'ClientIP', 'URL']:
    df = df.withColumn(i, F.regexp_extract('Detail',"{}=([^\|]+)".format(i),1))

df.show()

+-------+--------------------+-----+------+--------+-----------+
| Source|              Detail|Event|Device|ClientIP|        URL|
+-------+--------------------+-----+------+--------+-----------+
|Network|Event=01|Device=M...|   01|Mobile|10.0.0.0|example.com|
+-------+--------------------+-----+------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks. Originally I was thinking of pulling the column names from the data itself to save some manual typing for the schema since there're many columns but the solution you post works fine too.

Answer (score 1):

No need to write UDF for this thing, you can apply a number of alternatives and achieve this, Here is one of the alternative:-

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import functions

INPUT_PATH = 'network.log'

sc = SparkContext("local", "NetworkEvent")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

raw = sqlContext.read.json(INPUT_PATH)

detail_col = functions.split(raw['Detail'], '\|')

cols_to_be = raw.select([functions.split(detail_col.getItem(i), "=").getItem(0).alias("col_"+str(i)) for i in range(4)]).first()

for i in range(4):
    raw = raw.withColumn(
        cols_to_be["col_"+str(i)], 
        functions.split(detail_col.getItem(i), "=").getItem(1)
    )


raw.show()

+--------------------+-------+-----+------+--------+-----------+
|              Detail| Source|Event|Device|ClientIP|        URL|
+--------------------+-------+-----+------+--------+-----------+
|Event=01|Device=M...|Network|   01|Mobile|10.0.0.0|example.com|
+--------------------+-------+-----+------+--------+-----------+
```

**Hope your Details data should follow a pattern.**

Comment: Yes the `Detail` column has fixed pattern. Thanks for the solution~